# Updating db after dragndrop from RecyclerView/ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-sqlite, android-support-library

Implemented drag'ndrop for RecyclerView via ItemTouchHelper, so user can change order of items by dragging them up or down.

As by spec - the movement ends when `ItemTouchHelper.Callback#clearView` is called by android support library, so we need to update DB here (sqlite) and change order of dragged item and others (which were affected) - means ~a few requests to DB.

But as I see  `clearView` is called from GUI thread we can't do it from there (a few requests can be quite heavy depending on DB indexes and number of affected items).

So what are the best practices here?
Or just triggering DB updates from `clearView` via `android.os.AsyncTask` ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did via `android.os.AsyncTask`: moved all DB interactions there.